# State gets Updated only when we click on the button twice and not once by using Recat Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

1. I need to show only the highest value when I click on the button.
   But here the state is getting updated only when we click on the
   button twice and not once.
2. Can we do this using ES6 features like the `filter` method? Here I did it by using a `for` loop:

```
const [dataObject, setdataObject] = useState([{}]);
const [filterData, setfilterData] = useState({});

const showMillions = () => {
  // //console.log(dataObject);
  let x = 0;
  let name = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < dataObject.length; i++) {
    // console.log(dataObject);
    if (dataObject[i].money > x) {
      x = dataObject[i].money;
      name = dataObject[i].name;
    }
  }
  setfilterData(name);
  for (let i = 0; i < dataObject.length; i++) {
    if (filterData === dataObject[i].name) {
      setdataObject([dataObject[i]]);
    }
  }
};
<div><button className="btn btn-dark" onClick={showMillions} >Show Millionaires</button></div>
```

Comment: Hey, I guess you forgot to add the part with the button code to the example.

Comment: Added, Can you check once, Why we need to double click the button to update the State

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had to click the button twice because the `setfilterData(name)` is asynchronous. You can either use useEffect or use the `name` instead of `filterData` in the last for loop.

```
const [dataObject, setdataObject] = useState([{}]);
const [filterData, setfilterData] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    // using filter
    setDataObject(dataObject.filter((item) => item.name === filterData));
}, [filterData]);

const showMillions = () => {
    // //console.log(dataObject);
    let x = 0;
    let name = '';

    for (let i = 0; i < dataObject.length; i++) {
        // console.log(dataObject);
        if (dataObject[i].money > x) {
             x = dataObject[i].money;
             name = dataObject[i].name;
        }
    }
    setfilterData(name);
  }
};
<div><button className="btn btn-dark" onClick={showMillions} >Show Millionaires</button></div>
```

Comment: Can you look at this Issue once, Here is the link, please help me, tell me what I did wrong...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64366115/unable-to-bind-the-radio-button-and-checkbox-data-on-button-click-in-react-hooks